# If A is a proper closed subalgebra of $C(X)$ ($X$ compact) and A $\subseteq I_{x_0}$ then $A = I_{x_0}$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact set. Suppose $A$ is a proper, closed subalgebra of $C(X)$ that separates points.

1. Then $A \subseteq I_{x_0} = \{f \in C(X) : f(x_0) = 0\}$ for some unique $x_0 \in X$.

I understand this part / the proof. But the next two parts of the question confuse me.

2. Show that $B = \{ f + \lambda : f \in A, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is equal to $C(X)$.

I think I understand his *if* we had $\lambda \neq 0$ but the question didn’t. Was this a typo or is this true?

Edit to clarify: if we had that $g = f + \lambda$ for a non-zero lambda then I think I get it. We could (I think) show $B$ is a closed algebra that separates points and vanishes nowhere. So, by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, $B=C(X)$.

3. Use part 2 to show that $A = I_{x_0}$.

I don’t get this but it probably doesn’t help that I’m confused about 2.

Comment: Do you want to specify that your functions are real valued?

Comment: Sorry, yeah. We’ve been using the notation $C(X)$ to refer to continuous functions from X to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For part (2), you let $\lambda$ vary.   Your comments suggest that you are thinking of $\lambda$ as fixed.

Comment: @fredgoodman Hm. Yes I guess I was thinking of lambda as fixed but, even if we can vary lambda, wouldn’t we still have g(x0) = 0 for some functions?

Comment: But there is no point at which they all vanish, which is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

As to 2, the set $B$ is all functions of the form $f+\lambda$ where we can pick any $f \in A$ and any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. It's clear $B$ vanishes nowhere, so if you can show $B$ is a closed subalgebra you're done (as $A \subseteq B$, $B$ also separates points, as $A$ does).

As to 3. pick any $g$ in $I_{x_0}$. Then by 2. $g = f+\lambda$ for some $f \in A$ and some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. But $0 = g(x_0)  =f(x_0) + \lambda$. By 1. $f \in I_{x_0}$ as well, so $f(x_0) = 0$ and so $\lambda = 0$ and hence $g =f \in A$ and we have $I_{x_0} \subseteq A$ and 1. already gives us the other inclusion.

Comment: My problem is that it is not clear to me why B vanishes nowhere.

Comment: @JaneDoe If $f+\lambda_0$ vanishes at some $p$, $f+(\lambda_0 + 1)$ does not, and both are in the set. A function in $B$ can be $0$ at some point, as long as not *all* members of $B$ do as well.

Comment: @JaneDoe check your version of Stone-Weierstrass for the conditions you have to check for $B$. Maybe you just need a constant non-zero function (which you have as you can take $f = 0, \lambda=1$, say).